# Getting an error in jQuery when I try to autosave a form field with an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm trying to get a form field in a rails 3 project to autosave when it is changed. I'm attempting to do this with the following jQuery ajax call:

```
$j("#list_" + <%= item.list_id.to_s %> + "_item_" + <%=item.id.to_s %>).live("change", 
 function(){
      $j.ajax({ 
           beforeSend: function(request) {
               request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript"); 
           },
           type: 'POST',
           url: '<%= list_text_item_path(List.find(item.list_id), TextItem.find(item.id)) %>/update',
           data: {
                value: $j(this).val(),
                id: '<%= item.id.to_s %>',
                list_id: '<%= item.list_id.to_s %>'
           },
           success: function(){
                alert("success");
           } 
      });
 });
```

Whenever the text box is changed, I get the following error in jQuery:

```
 (c.value || "").replace is not a function
```

This is in both jQuery-1.5.min.js. I also had the same error happen with jQuery-1.4.2.min.js. (I updated to 1.5 to see if that would help anything.)

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?
Thanks so much.

Edit: Oh crap, when getting my HTML to post I realized I had the .live() call attached to the form input element's container div and not the form input element itself. I'm having a separate issue but I guess I'll post that once I figure out what might be causing it...

Comment: can you show a snippet of your html and the renderered finished js code?

Comment: Do you have a backtrace for this error, from, say, Firebug?  My best guess is that `c` in the error is the hash you pass to `ajax()` as `data:`, and that `$j(this).val()` is somehow not giving you a string (!?), hence `.replace()` not being one of its methods.  But it's hard to say without seeing what function calls led up to that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I figured it out... a careless error. I had the input element in a HTML list item, and I had the .live() function call attached to the li id rather than the input element id. Thanks for the help above guys.