# Autosaving changes to textfields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

My question is very similar to this one: [Getting an error in jQuery when I try to autosave a form field with an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911170/getting-an-error-in-jquery-when-i-try-to-autosave-a-form-field-with-an-ajax-call)

But the only problem with me is that my situation is more complex. I have a form which has 2 sections. To each section the user can add rows while inputting their data. Each row has a text field and a select box. I need to update the database values of these text fields and select boxes as they change.

Since these all are added on the fly, their ids are different. Ideally I would like to use onchange for each textfield and select box and call required functions which will make ajax call to update respective values. But when I try calling a function onchange, nothing happens. I am wondering if this use is deprecated in Rails 3 in favour of unobtrusive js. 
Here's how my haml for the textfield looks:

```
= builder.text_field "regular_expenditure", :value => val, :title => builder.object.regular_expenditure > 0 ? "" : '0.00', :size => 7, :class => "defaultText", :onchange => "javascript:sendGivenupAmount('challenge_givenup_items_attributes_#{@given_up.rindex(given_up)}_regular_expenditure', '#{given_up.id}');"
```

In my js file:

```
function sendGivenupAmount(){
    alert('in function');
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks in advance for any help

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support. I think I found a solution. I just made some changes to the view and accessed the elements through DOM in jquery. I could manage getting around it.

Thanks,
M